# Use body stream parameter in WebApi controller's action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I currently read input stream from body like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    byte[] array = new byte[Request.ContentLength.Value];

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(array))
    {
        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

I would like to specify the input parameter in the methods signature, due to testing and swagger generation.

Is it possible to specify the input parameter as stream somehow?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Stream body) ...
```

Comment: Did you try my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086909/use-body-stream-parameter-in-webapi-controllers-action/44334250#44334250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create custom attribute and custom parameter binding.

Here is my implementation of `FromContent` attribute and `ContentParameterBinding` binding:

```
public class ContentParameterBinding : FormatterParameterBinding
{
    private struct AsyncVoid{}
    public ContentParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor, descriptor.Configuration.Formatters,
               descriptor.Configuration.Services.GetBodyModelValidator())
    {

    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
                                                HttpActionContext actionContext,
                                                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
                                                HttpActionContext actionContext,
                                                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var binding = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding;

        if (binding.ParameterBindings.Length > 1 ||
            actionContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
        {
            var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<AsyncVoid>();
            taskSource.SetResult(default(AsyncVoid));
            return taskSource.Task as Task;
        }

        var type = binding.ParameterBindings[0].Descriptor.ParameterType;

        if (type == typeof(HttpContent))
        {
            SetValue(actionContext, actionContext.Request.Content);
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            tcs.SetResult(actionContext.Request.Content);
            return tcs.Task;
        }
        if (type == typeof(Stream))
        {
            return actionContext.Request.Content
            .ReadAsStreamAsync()
            .ContinueWith((task) =>
            {
                SetValue(actionContext, task.Result);
            });
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only HttpContent and Stream are supported for [FromContent] parameters");
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class FromContentAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter");

        return new ContentParameterBinding(parameter);
    }
}
```

Now you can

```
    public async Task<string> Post([FromContent]Stream contentStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(contentStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        return "OK";
    }
```

However it doesn't help with `swagger` :(

Comment: Any solution for .Net Core ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to create your model binder for streams:

```
public class StreamBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then you should create model binder provider for it:

```
public class StreamBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Stream))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(StreamBinder));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And register it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new StreamBinderProvider());
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Stream body) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

AS Web Api don't Bind stream in model binding this won't work. Instead if you need parameter stream you can use custom Model binding

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Extract the posted data from the request
        // Convert the base64string to Stream
        // Extract the model from the bindingcontext
        // Assign the model's property with their values accordingly   
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ApiActionResult SaveDocument([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]DocumentVM contentDTO)
```